# Classes and Abtract methods

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, abstraction

So I have this plain code here and I'm trying to make sense of these but I end up with a lot of errors and such. The main thing I need to do is to declare a **Person** class with a **Hello** abstract method, and then declare a **Student** class that is derived from the **Person** class and overrides its **Hello** method.

here is the code below:

```
public class Person{
  public abstract void Hello();
}
  class Student: Person {
    public override void Hello() {
 Console.Write("Hello there");
}}
```

Comment: "but I end up with a lot of errors" Can you show the error messages?

Comment: main.cs(11,26): error CS0513: `Person.Hello()' is abstract but it is declared in the non-abstract class `Person'

main.cs(10,14): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)

these are the errors. I ran them on onlinegdb

Answer (score 2):

**Compiler Error CS0513**

> 'function' is abstract but it is contained in nonabstract class.
> A method cannot be an abstract member of a nonabstract class.

Key is *A method cannot be an abstract member of a nonabstract class*

You need make `Person` class an abstract class

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public abstract void Hello();
}
```

Comment: so what should i replace?

Comment: @StellarisGhost you don't replace anything.  Fabio already gave you the answer...mark your `Person` class with the abstract keyword.  Your code will compile just fine after that.

Comment: I marked the person class but, it showed 1 error.
error CS5001: Program `a.out' does not contain a static `Main' method suitable for an entry point

so do I need to declare a Main method?

Comment: also, thank you for the help, you guys. :)

Comment: Really :) [Compiler Error CS5001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs5001#:~:text=This%20error%20occurs%20when%20no,such%20as%20lower%2Dcase%20main%20.)